# Link component props passed showing undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass props via Link component

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/admin", state: { fromNotification: true } }}></Link>
```

and when I'm console logging it from the child component I'm getting state as undefined. [image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you are console logging `history`, `location`, and `match` objects I'll assume you are using `react-router` v5. Can you share how you are declaring your routes and routed components, and the specific component doing the logging? I.E. the router and routes, and the component?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the state using the `state` attribute (separate it from `to`):

```
<Link to="/admin" state={{ fromNotification: true }}></Link>
```

Comment: . It's still showing me "undefined". Is there any other way to pass data to child components?